# Error "Reverse auth credentials are invalid" on Twitter Reverse Auth

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I am trying to implement Reverse Auth in an iOS PhoneGap / Cordova application.

I have Step 1 working correctly - my server performs a Token Request and returns the OAuth-Header-Like response to the mobile application.

But Step 2 isn't working.  The response from Step 1 is sent to "/oauth/access_token" but I receive the response:
Reverse auth credentials are invalid

Here is what my Step 1 response looks like:

```
OAuth oauth_token="xxx", oauth_timestamp="1361189727", oauth_nonce="QoUtVy4wchGbrSg7biruOIqsTU7G5gZHix9K7a5yU0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="qcCuBxaYFJRVi0C1rpuqygSg6Bs%3D", oauth_consumer_key="xxx", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Here is what my Step 2 code is:

```
NSDictionary *step2Params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[step2Params setValue:TW_CONSUMER_KEY forKey:@"x_reverse_auth_target"];
[step2Params setValue:step1ResponseString:@"x_reverse_auth_parameters"];
NSURL *authTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:TW_OAUTH_URL_AUTH_TOKEN];
id<GenericTwitterRequest> step2Request =
[self requestWithUrl:authTokenURL
          parameters:step2Params
       requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST];
[step2Request setAccount:selectedTwitterAccount];
[step2Request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *step2error)
```

I am using this plugin to handle the Reverse Auth calls:
https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/SocialAuthenticationPlugin/blob/master/iOS/SocialAuthenticationPlugin.m

Any help on what is going wrong?

The Step 1 response is in the form described in the docs ("oauth header like") and Step 2 just passes that exact string to Twitter along with my consumer key.  What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can perform a reverse auth by sending the step1 request from my device (the ios simulator), but when I make the request from my server and pass it back to device, step2 doesn't work. Are other developers just packaging their consumer secrets with their ios apps and running both requests on the device?

Comment: Can anyone show me how to perform step one properly? I cannot find ANYTHING showing how to do this, with the exception of an example project provided by Sean Cook which is not easy to read or understand